# Can I add a self defined layers in google earth through the kml?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I want a function ,when I choose myself defined layer,then the aim come out.such as in Google earth, when I choose the "water body outlines",the water area outlines displayed.Can I achieve this in the Google earth? or there is another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layers are provided by the Google Earth server, not by KML. So no - it is not possible to add custom layers to GE using straight KML.

You could of course put the water body outlines into a KML object and have it be displayed in Google Earth. It'd show up under the "places" tree (in temporary places -- until the user chooses to save it to my places.) When your KML object is in temp/my places the user can toggle it on and off just like a layer, from the user perspective it looks and feels the same.

From the administrator's perspective it's not the best approach because your underlying KML becomes easily obtainable. All the user has to do is click on your KML object in temp/my places and press CTRL+C to copy the KML to the clipboard. Then they can simply CTRL+V into notepad (or some other text editor) and read/edit the KML. Something to keep in mind.

If you have a Google Earth Enterprise (Fusion) Server, the sky's the limit. You can bake whatever you want into the layers panel. But that's only if you have an enterprise server and all your users are using GE Enterprise.

Comment: thank you very much!but there is one more question:Can myself add a water body outlines as the Google provided?I may use a Polygon.but I feel this is not a good solution,because myself may not control the details.can there other method?

Comment: Im not sure why you mean by "Myself may not control the details" -- you can make a KML polygon, which is what I would suggest, in any way you want. If you know the points along the outline what's the problem? (Please accept and/or upvote answers you find useful.)

Comment: oh!because I think the water body outlines is a little complex.I wonder if Google can offer the outline info .but now I knew may be make a KML polygon by myself is the answer.thank you very much!

Comment: You can probably find some kind of vector data file from the US Geological Survey or the US Census Bureau. Not sure how you'd convert that to a KML. Google Earth pro _might_ be able to load the vector data for you -- never tried myself. If you had a fusion server it would definitely load it.